# Probability that $k$ variables of multivariate Gaussian are positive

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

You have a basket of $n$ assets whose returns are multivariate normal with zero mean. The correlation between any pair of assets is 1/2. What is the probability that $k$ of the assets will have positive return?

I think the answer should be $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \frac{1}{2^n}$, regardless of what the correlation is. Is this correct?

**Simulation**:

```
import numpy as np

def simu(n, rho):
    mean = [0] * n
    cov = np.ones((n,n))*rho + (1-rho)*np.eye(n) # diagonal covariance
    
    N = 5000
    x = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, N).T
    y = [sum([x[i][j]>0 for i in range(n)]) for j in range(N)]
    print(np.histogram(y))

simu(10,0.5)
Output: (array([457, 470, 481, 465, 426, 447, 447, 444, 487, 876])
```

Using simulation, for $\rho=1$, I get the probability to be 0.5 for $k=0$ and $k=n$ and 0 for other $k$. How to prove this?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Zhanxiong: added comment.

Comment: Can you run a simulation to validate your conjecture?

Comment: If $\rho=0$ then your expression looks reasonable.  If $\rho=1$ then clearly not (you will get $k=n$ or $k=0$ each with probability $\frac12$).  So it is likely to be wrong for other $\rho \not=0$.

Comment: Consider the following construction of the $n$ assets.  We have $n$ i.i.d. zero-mean, unit variance Gaussian variates, and we create another (1) zero-mean, unit variance Gaussian.  We now add the $(n+1)^{th}$ variate to all the others.  The $n$ new variates all have pairwise correlations equal to 0.5.   Is the probability that any given pair of assets have a positive return equal to 0.25?

Comment: @jbowman I am not sure that would be what "multivariate normal" usually means

Comment: Simulation suggests to me that $\rho=\frac12$ is a particularly interesting case with a multivariate normal.  You should try it.

Comment: *Look* at the case $n=2,k=2.$  Your formula gives $2!/(2!0!) 2^{-2}=1/4.$ That is obviously wrong because it implies each of the four quadrants has a $1/4$ probability, making the distribution spherically symmetric -- and it's not.  The answer will be given by the solid angle subtended by a vertex of a symmetric simplex (*e.g.,* tetrahedron with $n=3$) whose value is immediately given by the Gauss-Bonnet theorem.

Comment: @Henry: I have added my code, and the result for $\rho=0.5$.

Comment: The question about $\rho=1$ is trivial, because that's the case of perfect correlation: almost surely all standardized values are equal.  By symmetry, the chance all are positive equals the chance all are negative and nothing else has any nonzero chance.

Comment: @Bravo You should have $11$ values in your output for $k=0,1,\ldots,9,10$ but you only have $10$.  I suspect your histogram function have added the last two together.  I also suspect that if you used more than $5000$ simulations, it would be even more suggestive that each of the $11$ values seemed approximately equally likely.

Comment: @whuber: Can you give some references for the tetrahedron angle calcs? An answer would be most welcome too :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose $(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ has a standard multivariate normal distribution with common correlation $\frac12$. Then you have the following equality in distribution:

$$(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) \stackrel{d} = \left(\frac1{\sqrt 2}Z_1+\frac1{\sqrt 2}Z_0,\frac1{\sqrt 2}Z_2+\frac1{\sqrt 2}Z_0,\ldots,\frac1{\sqrt 2}Z_n+\frac1{\sqrt 2}Z_0\right)\,,$$

where $Z_0,Z_1,\ldots,Z_n$ are i.i.d standard normal variables.

Using this, we can calculate the probability that exactly $k$ ($0\le k\le n$) of the variables are positive.

For example,

\begin{align}
P\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^k \{X_j>0\},\bigcap_{j=k+1}^n \{X_j<0\}\right)&=E\left[(P(Z_1>-Z_0\mid Z_0))^k (P(Z_{k+1}<-Z_0\mid Z_0))^{n-k}\right] 
\\&=E\left[(1-\Phi(-Z_0))^k \cdot (\Phi(-Z_0))^{n-k}\right]
\\&=E\left[(\Phi(Z_0))^k \cdot ((1-\Phi(Z_0))^{n-k}\right]\,,
\end{align}

where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the standard normal distribution function.

As $\Phi(Z_0)$ is uniform on $(0,1)$, this probability can be written in terms of the Beta function:

$$\int_0^1 y^k(1-y)^{n-k}\,\mathrm dy=B(k+1,n-k+1)$$

The desired probability is therefore $$\binom{n}{k}B(k+1,n-k+1)=\frac1{n+1}\,,$$

as in @Henry's answer.

Comment: The idea of approaching the problem is great (+1). Just one modification is needed: the probability of interest should be $\binom{n}{k} \times P(X_1>0, \ldots, X_k>0,X_{k+1}<0 ,\ldots,X_n<0)$
. After making this correction, your analytical solution will agree with @Henry's simulation result.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thank you.

Comment: +1.  It's nice that this agrees with the fact that a simplex in $\mathbb R^k$ has $k+1$ vertices ;-).

Comment: @StubbornAtom In fact, for any $k \in \{0, \ldots, n\}$, $\binom{n}{k}B(k + 1, n - k + 1)$ is $\frac{1}{n + 1}$.  That means, the distribution of # of positive assets is uniform on $\{0, 1, \ldots, n\}$.

Answer (score 4):

Your conjecture of a binomial distribution would only apply when $\rho=0$. For positive $\rho$ it is intuitive to expect a more dispersed distribution, though still symmetric about the mean $\frac n2$.

Your simulation is useful, though `np.histogram` is the wrong summary function to use.  Here is mine in R, with $n=10$ and $\rho=\frac12$ with one million simulations:

```
library(mvtnorm)
set.seed(2023)
positivemultivariatenormal <- function(dimen, rho, cases){
    sims <- rmvnorm(cases, sigma=diag(dimen)*(1-rho)+rep(rho,dimen^2))
    table(rowSums(sims > 0)) / cases
    }
positivemultivariatenormal(dimen=10, rho=1/2, cases=10^6)
#        0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7 
# 0.090877 0.090430 0.091604 0.090452 0.090728 0.091824 0.090943 0.090504 
#        8        9       10 
# 0.090822 0.090757 0.091059
```

This suggests that with $\rho=\frac12$ you get a uniform distribution with probabilities of $\frac1{n+1}$, which with $n=10$ is about $0.0909$.  Trying with the same $\rho=\frac12$ and different $n$ seems to confirm this.